# Which word? enforceability/enforceable/enforcement/enforcive/enforcing in nature?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

Context: I'm trying to tell the reader that the guidelines are intended/designed to enforce previous rules. The new guidelines do not add new rules, just enforcing previous ones. How to I write this?:

1. These guidelines are of enforceability in nature
2. These guidelines are of enforceable in nature
3. These guidelines are of enforcement in nature
4. These guidelines are of enforcive in nature
5. These guidelines are of enforcing in nature

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to say. What rules could there be that enforce nature? It seems to me that nature makes and enforces its own rules, and there isn't any concept of adding new ones to it that I can think of. But that aside, I think your "guidelines are intended to enforce previous rules" is the clearest thing that you are saying here. I don't see where nature comes into it, though.

Comment: You don't need _of_ at all. You want an adjective that describes the nature of the guidelines. According to Merriam-Webster , _enforcive_ is obsolete, so I would suggest _enforcing_ (which functions as an adjective).

Comment: Do you mean enforcing the rules, which means compelling people to follow them, with penalties such as fines or dismissal? Or do you mean reinforcing the rules, which means strengthening them?